# Diferença real entre operador ponto (.) e operador seta (->) em C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, operadores

Qual a diferença real entre os dois operadores.

Sei que o operador `(->)` se utiliza quando a variável é um ponteiro, e que ele equivale a `(*ptr).membro`. Pois bem, se eu declaro um ponteiro do tipo de uma estrutura, devo utilizar o operador seta. Caso eu declare uma variável ordinária do tipo estrutura, devo utilizar o operador ponto. Isso eu sei.

O que eu realmente gostaria de saber é: qual a vantagem de um em relação ao outro? Quando devo utilizar um em vista do outro? Ainda não vi a vantagem de ter dois operadores que aparentemente fazem a mesma coisa.

Comment: Acho que não é questão de "vantagem", é uma ênfase (sintática) da linguagem para deixar claro quando você está lidando com ponteiros para objetos (e usa `->`), ou com os próprios objetos (e usa `.`).

Comment: p->v seria um atalho para (*p).v, se existir alguma vantagem, creio que seja em organização.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Ambos são equivalentes**, não há uma vantagem em utilizar um ou outro, normalmente o copilador tem algo que se chama "syntactic sugar", que na verdade é uma facilitação para escrever o codigo, isso é muito visível no java onde você pode trocar um + por uma chama a **new StringBuilder()**.

> Se existir alguma Vantagem, seria na organização/legibilidade do código !

```
(*(*(*a).b).c).d // não intuitivo

a->b->c->d // intuitivo
```

Procurei uma referencia para comprovar o que vou dizer agora mas não achei, em alguns copiladores, existe a substituição pre-copilação, o copilador antes de realizar o c-object  substitui todas as ocorrências de -> por (*p).v, sei que isso está documentado nos livros da OCA do java, pode ser que o mesmo ocorra no c.

Comment: Então dado um tipo `struct`  um tipo `*a` da `struct` e um tipo `a` também da `struct` vão surtir o mesmo efeito?

Answer (score 14):

A diferença real é que o primeiro é uma referência ao membro, você está simplesmente dizendo que deve pegar o dado do membro e o segundo é uma desreferência do ponteiro contido no membro, está dizendo que deve pegar o valor apontado pelo ponteiro no membro. É apenas açúcar sintático e a vantagem é escrever e ler mais facilmente. Fica mais óbvio ver `->` e saber o que está acontecendo do que interpretar `(*ptr).membro`.

O que isto faz?

```
(*(*(*a).b).c).d
```

E isto?

```
a->b->c->d
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/PointerSyntax.c).

Este está dizendo para pegar o valor apontado por `d` que é membro de `c` que é membro de `b` que por sua vez é membro de `a`. O primeiro faz a mesma coisa mas não vou nem arriscar lê-lo em voz alta. Ser explícito na intenção é melhor.

Em C++ ainda há a diferença que o "operador de seta" pode ser sobrecarregado.

C foi feito para ser um *assembly* portátil e não pensou muito nas facilidades para o programador. Se você pensar que o normal em um programa é trabalhar com valores finais e não com ponteiros, C é bem chato. Por usabilidade o normal seria dizer que quer pegar o ponteiro por exceção. Mas pela filosofia do C isto não é o ideal. Ela sempre procurou facilitar o acesso rápido e não a usabilidade. Eram os anos 70.

De fato há discussões sobre como o `->` é desnecessário na linguagem. Realmente é possível não usá-lo mas tinha que ser definido no começo da linguagem. É possível o compilador saber como o acesso deve ser feito apenas com `.` mas [percebeu-se isto tarde demais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist). Inicialmente o `->` não era *syntax sugar*.

Comment: Gostei da resposta que explicou sobre o C++ e o "como o C foi planeja".