# Struct com vetor não está funcionando

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, operadores, struct

Eu estou tentando usar vetores e `struct`, porém não está funcionado.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Atleta {

    float notas[5];

} atleta;

void receberNotas(atleta* l) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("Digite %d nota: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%f", &l[i].notas);
    }
}

void mostrarNotas(atleta *l) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("\n%.2f", l[i].notas);
    }
}
int main()
{
    atleta *a;
    receberNotas(&a);
    mostrarNotas(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Não consegui usar esse operador -> para acessar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários problemas. Estou partindo do princípio que um atleta tem 5 notas. Se não for isso, tem mais coisas erradas.

Tem que alocar a memória para a estrutura. Preferi optar por alocação dinâmica com [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc). E [não precisa passar com `&`, ele já é um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101).

O acesso ao índice deve ser feito em `notas` e não no objeto do atleta, no caso foi usado `l` (nome ruim de variável). A não ser que são 5 atletas com uma nota cada (seria estranho usar uma estrutura para isso).

E o acesso ao membro deve ser feito com o operador [`->`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) já que se trata de uma referência.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Atleta {
    float notas[5];
} atleta;
void receberNotas(atleta* l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Digite %d nota: ", (i + 1));
        scanf("%f", &l->notas[i]);
    }
}
void mostrarNotas(atleta *l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("\n%.2f", l->notas[i]);
}
int main() {
    atleta *a = malloc(sizeof(atleta));
    receberNotas(a);
    mostrarNotas(a);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oiWaJY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/stmvuaea-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Struct.c).

Veja a [Diferença real entre operador ponto (.) e operador seta (->) em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51180/101)

Comment: não lembrava alguns conceitos, fiquei por um tempo sem estudar.