# Para que serve o operador "->" em c?

Tags: c

Eu estou estudando as listas ligadas ou encadeadas
E eu vi esse operador em um código que eu vi 
Eu já procurei na internet e em livros e não achei nada sobre 
Para que isso serve?

Comment: Essa pergunta já tem [resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51180/diferen%C3%A7a-real-entre-operador-ponto-e-operador-seta-em-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a->b é o equivalente a (*a).b, ele pega o membro chamado bar da estrutura onde foo está sendo apontado. É basicamente um atalho para (*a).b

Mais informações: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c